# Write numerical parameters lines in text file in Ipython using writelines?

Tags: python

I am trying to write lines in software (spaceclaim) that has IPython embedded, perhaps with not with all libraries available.

I am trying to write two parameters in two rows under each other, but since they are numbers, I should use `str(a)` for them, but I can not use `\n` between the two parameters to change the line. What happens is that I can write only one parameter to a text file but if I want more than one, then Python concatenates all in one line and ignores the comma.

```py
import os
loc=os.getcwd()
filename = loc1+ '\\params.txt'

tw= [str(A), str(B)]
outfile = open(filename, "w")
outfile.writelines(tw)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Is something missing in my question ? mostly in similar question I have only found already text data to be written to text file but with write command

Comment: Write your input is, what your wanted output is and what kind of output you get, and the program used to get this output. Some kind of broken English text does not help. I have no clue what you want to do.

Comment: @rioV8 sorry but which part of my question is written in broken English ? while also someone answered correctly before you comment. I have explained in the question what I tried and what happens. I want numbers in a column, my code writes them all in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you make a list? Just use a string.

```py
tw = str(A) + '\n' + str(B)
with open(filename, 'w')as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(tw)
    outfile.close()
```

And I just want to say:
Open a file in `w` mode means that when you write something it overwrites everything. Maybe your looking for `a` which means append.

Second you have `loc =os.getcwd()` and then you use `filename = loc**1** + '\\params.txt'`

And more little thing. You can use `/` instead of `\\` in a path.

Comment: absolutely yes ! I'll try this now , thanks a lot. I really needed this answer, but I got an uninformed negative vote

Comment: probably because you can't tell anyone that you tried your best

Comment: but you know it's different and it's a good question, and you gave a great answer